# Alternatives for Eclipse IDE on Android Devices

Tags: android, eclipse

For work, sometimes I need to change my laptop for my tablet, and as a developer is hard to find an IDE to replace Eclipse in my android device.

I develop web apps with servlets based on Java.

Does someone know (and try) any alternaties to be used on Android compatible with Eclipse projects?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `Visual Studio Code` ?

Comment: Technically off-topic as you are asking tor a recommendation such as a "book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". That said, development ON an Android device can be done with [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) as it does support [a number of development languages](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Development_Environments) Don't know how easy/hard Eclipse project support is under Termux.

Comment: In android? no. Can I use it to develop Java Apps and run servlets in Android as I do with eclipse in windows? Thank u @inkredusk :)

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang and thanks for ur answer. I dont need books, tools, etc Im just asking for alternative to eclipse to develop in Android. Whit Termux, can I develop java app for webservelts? I have all my apps under eclipse projects, so I didnt Know If I could migrate it (and continue developing) in an android device.